# Wave equation $u_{xx}+u_{xt}- u_{tt}=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Does anybody know how we can solve the equation $u_{xx}+  u_{xt}-  u_{tt}=0$ with $u(x,0):=g(x)$ and $u_t(x,0):=h(x)?$ I mean it is known how to do this for the wave equation [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation) but I don't know how to do this in the more general case with the mixed term in it.

Comment: How about using the Fourier transform?

Comment: ah, we are only allowed to use very basic tricks.

Comment: @Roadrunner324 What is a "very basic trick"?

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of characteristics? I will provide a hint anyway.

Comment: no, unfortunately not. well, i am looking for things like substitutions, or some multivariable calculus manipulations. things like that

Comment: Manipulation of the Fourier transform or the method of characteristics would be my best bet. There are other methods but they are more advanced. For example, the method of descent (by Hadamard) says that if $u$ solves the wave equation in $\mathbb{R}^{1+n}$, then it is a solution of the wave equation in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^{1+n}$ which is independent of the last variable $x_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: note that your equation can be expressed as follows:

$$(D^2_x + D_x D_t  - D^2_t)\, u = (D_x- \varphi^- D_t)  (D_x - \varphi^+ D_t) u  = 0, $$ where $\varphi^{\pm} = (-1 \pm \sqrt{5})/2$ are the two solutions of $s^2+s-1=0$. What if we now define $v := (D_x - (-1+\sqrt{5})D_t/2) u$? Can you solve 1st order PDEs?

Cheers!

---

Of course, you will have noticed that $-\varphi^- = \varphi$ is the so-called golden ratio, satisfying $\varphi = 1 + \varphi^{-1}$.

Comment: There is a $+$ in front of $D_xD_t$.

Comment: Definitely some cosmetic surgery was required!

Comment: Happy to help!  @Roadrunner324

Comment: Still an error, the solutions of $s^2+s+1=0$ are $(-1\pm\sqrt{5})/2$.

Comment: Oh my... Sorry for the continuous editing.

Answer (score 5):

We are dealing with the wave equation $u_{xx}+u_{tt}-u_{tt}=0$. Notice that it has a mixed term. So we cannot use d'Alembert's formula here. (The formula assumes a difference of squares when "factoring" the derivatives.) Here, we have to "factor" the derivatives manually.

Note that we can rewrite our wave equation as $$\left( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial t} - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)u=0.$$ And "factoring" out the derivatives (using the quadratic formula to help) gives $$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)u=0.$$
Now set $\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. Then the wave equation becomes the Canonical form $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}u=0$$ or $u_{\xi \eta}=0$. Furthermore, the chain rules of $\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{d\xi}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{d\xi}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{d\eta}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{dt}{d\eta}$ imply $$\frac{dx}{d\xi}=1, \quad \frac{dx}{d\eta}=1, \quad \frac{dt}{d\xi}=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2, \quad \frac{dt}{d\eta}=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2.$$ Thus, we  obtain $$x=\xi+\eta, \quad t=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2\xi+\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2\eta,$$ which means we can use these to perform change of variables.

Can you finish the rest from here?

Comment: Don't you have a wrong sign on the first eq.?

Comment: Also, in the second equation you need the $+$ sign in front of the two fractions.

Comment: @enzotib Can you clarify this? I can't seem to pinpoint what you said for the second equation. I do see, however, that upon distributing I do not get back to the first one. :(

Comment: It should be $\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}2 \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \right)u=0$.

Answer (score 4):

I would try a solution of type $F(z)=F(x-ct)$, or $G(w)=G(x+ct)$. For $F$ this gives
$$
u_{xx}=F''(z)\\
u_{xt}=-cF''(z)\\
u_{tt}=c^2F''(z)
$$
so
$$
(1-c-c^2)F''(z)=0\implies c_{1,2}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}.
$$
So $F(x-c_it)$ is a solution for every choice of $F$.
Same reasoning for $G$.